# SimpleFramework XML: element with inner text and child elements

Tags: java, simple-framework

I have XML in this format:

```
<element1>
     some inner text
     <child1>11</child1>
     <child2>True</child2>
</element1>
```

And I try to map this XML on object by simple framework:

```
@Element(name = "element1")
public static class Something {

    @Element(required=false)
    public int child1;

    @Element(required=false)
    public boolean child2;

}
```

I can't change the XML and I need to map also value "some inner text" on some field in class. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to do that (and if it is possible). I tried @Text annotation but it can't be used together with @Element in one class.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: You can actually do this with version 2.6.9 and up. Use the following annotations, note the `@Text` annotation can be used with `@ElementListUnion`.

```
@Root
public static class Something {

    @Text 
    @ElementListUnion({
       @ElementList(entry="child1", type=Integer.class, inline=true),
       @ElementList(entry="child2", type=Boolean.class, inline=true)
    })
    public List<Object> values;
}
```

This can only be done as a hack job, by default simple does not support free text as it does not map consistently to an object. Here is how you can do it, however its probably not worth it unless this is a special case within a large file of cases that work well in Simple.

```
package org.simpleframework.xml.convert;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ValidationTestCase;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputNode;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeBuilder;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.OutputNode;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class HackJobToGrabFloatingTextTest extends ValidationTestCase {

   private static final String SOURCE =
   "<element1>\n"+
   "   some inner text\n"+
   "   <child1>11</child1>\n"+
   "   <child2>True</child2>\n" +
   "</element1>";

   private static class SomethingConverter implements Converter<Something> {

      public Something read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
         Object source = node.getSource();
         Element element = (Element)source;
         NodeList elements = element.getChildNodes();
         String child1 = null;
         String child2 = null;
         String text = "";
         for(int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
            Node next = elements.item(i);
            if(next.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
               text += next.getNodeValue();
            }
            if(next.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               if(next.getNodeName().equals("child1")) {
                  child1 = next.getTextContent();
               }
               if(next.getNodeName().equals("child2")) {
                  child2 = next.getTextContent();
               }
            }
         }
         return new Something(child1, child2, text.trim());
      }

      public void write(OutputNode node, Something car) throws Exception {
         // Free text not supported!!
      }
   }

   @Root(name = "element1")
   @Convert(SomethingConverter.class)
   public static class Something {
       public String child1;
       public String child2;
       public String text;
       public Something(String child1, String child2, String text) {
          this.child1 = child1;
          this.child2 = child2;
          this.text = text;
       }
   }

   public void testHackJob() throws Exception {
      Class<?> type = Class.forName("org.simpleframework.xml.stream.DocumentProvider");
      Constructor<?> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor();
      constructor.setAccessible(true);
      Object value = constructor.newInstance();
      Field[] fields = NodeBuilder.class.getDeclaredFields();

      for(Field field : fields) {
         if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("provider")) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, value);
         }
      }
      StringReader reader = new StringReader(SOURCE);
      InputNode source = NodeBuilder.read(reader);
      AnnotationStrategy strategy = new AnnotationStrategy();
      Persister persister = new Persister(strategy);
      Something something = persister.read(Something.class, source);

      assertNotNull(something);
      assertEquals(something.text, "some inner text");
      assertEquals(something.child1, "11");
      assertEquals(something.child2, "True");
   }
}
```

Comment: @ollo , will you please have a look at a similar question..http://stackoverflow.com/q/17462970/1334114